# write a distinct query on joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. ProductA and ProductB.

ProductA

```
ID Description

A1 ProdA1
B1 ProdB1
C1 ProdC1
D1 ProdD1
E1 ProdE1
```

ProductB

```
ID SubId

A1 112
A1 118
B1 111
B1 113
D1 117
D1 118
E1 115
E1 116
E1 117
```

I want to write a query which outputs all records from ProductA Table and SubId column from ProductB table such that if an ID from ProductA is Present in ProductB then it will display the SubId else NULL. So for the above tables, it will display following output.

```
ID Description SubId

A1  ProdA1      112
B1  ProdB1      111
C1  ProdC1      NULL
D1  ProdD1      117
E1  ProdE1      116
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: If you want to write it, then try writing it. Then if it doesn't work, come back and we can help you.

Comment: You can use `LEFT JOIN` for instance.

Comment: We can only assume the correct `SubId` for `E1` should be `115` rather than `116` as you have in your sample, since `115` is the minimum value for `E1` and your others all select the `MIN()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *if an ID from ProductA is Present in ProductB then it will display the SubId else NULL*

That is the purpose of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s. Otherwise, you are choosing the lowest value for `ProductB.subId` per `ID`, which implies an [aggregate `MIN()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx).

```
SELECT
  ProductA.ID,
  ProductA.Description,
  /* Aggregate MIN() to get the first SubId per Id */
  MIN(ProductB.SubId) AS SubId
FROM
  ProductA
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductB ON ProductA.ID = ProductB.ID
GROUP BY
  ProductA.ID,
  ProductA.Description
```

So what you are looking for based on your sample output really isn't a `DISTINCT` set, but an aggregate grouped set.

#### [Here's a demonstration on SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0722/1)

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.description, b.subId
FROM ProductA a
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT Id, MIN(subId) subid
  FROM ProductB
  GROUP BY ID
)b ON a.Id = b.Id
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2eda2/5)

Comment: ... You don't need the `DISTINCT`, given that `ProductA.Id` is (most likely) unique, and you group in your subquery.  Still, I think I'd prefer this, to grouping by both the id and the description.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - Yes, you are right. Actually I was trying something else, and I forgot it. Fixed now. Thanks.